# Mocha with Node: Only show logging for tests that fail

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, winston

I'm using node with mocha and winston. Is there a way to set it up so it only shows logs for failing tests?

Comment: @Brand's answer is 100% correct. I prefer to be more explicit and use `mocha --reporter min` instead of `mocha -R min`. Just another way to do the same thing.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you run with the min reporter you will only get full output on failed tests: `mocha -R min` or, if you prefer the verbose option, `mocha --reporter min`.

Comment: This does not suppress your application logs.

Answer (score 0):

As of writing (in 2022), there's now an npm package that does exactly this:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mocha-suppress-logs

I like it because I like the output from the default mocha reporter. It keeps all that, but hides console output for succeeding tests.

Answer (score -1):

Possible to use

```
if (!expect(next.called).to.be.true) {
        console.log("... further information")
}
```